# LargeTable collapse in itext7

Tags: java, itext7

I am a newbie using the **iText7 7.1.1** to create heavy tables with more than 1000+ rows, so followed [iText7 Large Table](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/clone-large-tables) example and write my Java code like:

```
int width = dataSet.getColumnNames().size();
Table table = new Table(new UnitValue[width], true);
document.addTable(table);
for (String header : dataSet.getColumnNames()) {
    table.addHeaderCell(header);
}
int count = 0;
for (String text : dataSet.getTexts()) {
    if (count++ % 10 == 0) {
        table.flush();
    }
    table.addCell(new Cell().setKeepTogether(true).add(new Paragraph(text)));
    ...
}
table.complete();
```

but when the table reach the end of the page, **sometimes** the bottom line of the table will collapse(disappear) like:

incomplete one
[image: incomplete one]

the normal one should like:
[image: complete one]

It's quit weird because the complete one is from the same PDF contains the incomplete one.

Comment: *"sometimes"* - is that reproducible? I.e. can you provide code with a specific set of data that always creates that problem?

Comment: the data is Set<Object> of something retrieve from database,and this happens 20 times in my case to create 25 pages PDF with full of table(incomplete one:complete one=20:5)every time.

Comment: @Byron this is a known issue and there is a ticket for it in itext internal backlog. I will give you an update here once it's resolved.

Comment: @Uladzimir Asipchuk thank you.